# Is there a way to prevent transactions becoming too expensive

Tags: ether, gas-price

[As the price of ethereum has goes up, the cost of making transactions increases as well.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/with-the-rising-ether-price-to-9-doesnt-this-mean-gas-costs-more) What methods are there to prevent making transactions from becoming unaffordable?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I'm asking about methods for maintaining affordable transactions with scaling costs. That question is asking if the price has increased

Comment: Apologies - I should have commented on why I think that question already answers yours. The top-voted (but not accepted) answer in that question talks about reducing the gas _price_, which helps maintain the overall cost of the transaction. (overall cost = gasUsed * gasCost) - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2760/52